# I made a jsfiddle of a responsive SO

Tags: discussion, design

[Original](http://jsfiddle.net/j5tLR/show/), [Responsive](http://jsfiddle.net/j5tLR/8/show/). I got rid of fixed widths and made percent widths. It starts to break at around 650px width, by then it could go to mobile styles.

What do you think? Could something like this be made real?

BTW, I would like to know what you like and don't like about it. Please leave comments so I can make a better version. Also, feel free to edit the CSS yourself!

Comment: But why, since we have a dedicated mobile site and a mobile application?

Comment: Because I have a 27" screen and it looks like crap. Ok, I've kind of gotten used to it now, but really? It's a thin stripe down the center of my monitor.

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting point.  I only have a 19" screen and it looks alright to me, so I'm not sure I share your use case.  You could always add it to your user-defined CSS for the site, though.

Comment: Of course, but if it can improve the site, it's a good idea to roll it out for everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd call this very first result *responsive*, but I wouldn't mind using something simple as this—if only to stop people from formatting posts to look okay on the regular site, without thinking about how their posts look on the mobile theme and all. (I still wouldn't use my browser full screen, but I hardly do that for any site.)

Comment: The first one? That was the unmodified version for comparison.

Comment: No, the second. Maybe people call "just scaling" responsive too. But: that's just a side note. My *"this very first result"* was meant to indicate that I understand that it's just a first try, not a finished implementation.

Comment: Oh. Well, it "responds" to resizing the window :)

Comment: Related: the declined [Can SO have a fluid vs. fixed-width layout?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/can-so-have-a-fluid-vs-fixed-width-layout/179781#179781)

Comment: I find this matter tends to be subjective. I, *for one*, prefer current layout because it reduces eye-movement, and I don't have to rotate my head! *(yeah, really subjective and maybe not even a strong argument, but opinion is opinion)*. So, if it would be really implemented, make it as optional.

Comment: True, @Andrew, I'm perfectly happy with the current width as well. But then: on other websites I also adjust my browser to what I feel makes reading easiest. If a fluid layout were implemented, I'd do the same for SO if needed. (Though I doubt I even need to change anything, as the "maximize" button on OS X often gets it right, and I often just manually resize to some width between 1100 and 1300 pixels.)

Comment: Ah, your 2nd version is much better already! As an aside, maybe the change in the URL I made was not perfect; http://fiddle.jshell.net/j5tLR/2/show/ also gets rid of the jsFiddle header, and hence of ugly scrollbars.

Comment: This is really cool, thanks for making the prototypes. However, I don't think hiding the linked and related questions is a good idea, because those are essential for finding duplicates, and finding closely related content in general. Maybe stuff them underneath or something?

Comment: @Cupcake Oh, good idea. I put them right above the footer.

Comment: I agree I have dual 2048 x 1152 monitors @ 24" and SO and all the other stack exchange sites take up 1/3 of my screen, the blanks on either side are just wasted space, I like the idea of being able to see an entire code block without having to artificially scroll the tiny code window!

Comment: If you rotate your screen by 1/4 turn to portrait orientation, the default layout will no longer seem to be too narrow.  But you might crane your neck looking up and down.

Comment: Enough with this newfangled "responsive" stuff. Let's put ads in the blank spaces

Comment: @Pekka http://jsfiddle.net/h2xZZ/

Comment: @bjb YES YES ----

Comment: As an aside: for a moment I thought [the new profile pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231112/profile-page-makeover-part-2-the-prototype) no longer use a fixed width either, but that's only on mobile...

Comment: I'm all for responsive but there needs to be a max width. This page looks ridiculous in some settings. Reading a single extremely long line of text is very difficult.

Comment: I have a 30'' monitor and I can't read that because it's too big. Max-width is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Should the question and the answers be in separate columns?

Comment: Perhaps...I can't really tell except that I don't like having to move my head to read the whole thing.

Comment: For all the people traumatised by reading incredibly wide columns of text, I have wonderful news - about thirty years ago window size became adjustable.

Comment: did you make up that dialog in the demo  ?  +1 for the time you spent on aliasing SO and madding up that interesting conversation