# Browser extension for small SO improvements

Tags: discussion

I want to volunteer some time to create a browser extension (Google Chrome) to make SOing simpler. For example, better shortcuts, viewing a question body from the questions list, etc. I want to spend a few days on it and currently gather requirements and suggestions here: https://github.com/AlexAtNet/sox

Your early feedback will make this project not useful only for me but for your as well.

What do you think?

**Update:** three initial proposals were created and j/k navigation for the list and `b` for loading the body are almost ready

Comment: Hm… review shortcuts… I can see robo reviewing as a result of those.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253487/2371861

Comment: I can add a required timeout for the review shortcuts. The problem is only that I like to use a keyboard only and it is now a bit complicated

Comment: How is this different from [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch)?

Comment: @rene As I see, SOUP fixes rendering issues in `View` (in MVC terms). I hope to add more advanced features, for example, question body loading (by SO API call) in the questions list.